# Multiply Bits with factor (GLSL)

Tags: glsl, opengl-es-2.0, glsles

I want to have a method which multiplies each bit in a number with a factor. For example if factor is 3, each bit in the number is used three times before the next bit in the number is used. 
I'm working with GLSL.

Answer (score 0):

Did it with C#

```
private int DuplicateBitsByFactor(int value, int factor)
    {
        var size = sizeof(ushort) * 8;
        var binaryString = new StringBuilder();

        for (var i = size; i >= 0; i--)
            for (var j = 0; j < factor; j++)
                binaryString.Append(GetBitOnLocation(value, i));

        var duplicateBitsByFactor = Convert.ToInt32(binaryString.ToString(), 2);
        return duplicateBitsByFactor;
    }

    private int GetBitOnLocation(int value, int location)
    {
        return (value & (1 << location)) == 0 ? 0 : 1;
    }
```

Any optimization?